# Group by returns empty dataframe and no error

Tags: pandas

**I try to `groupby` and `agg` but I receive an empty dataframe and no error.**

When I do this:

```
  df_temp = df.groupby('Col1')['InfoType', 'InfoLabel1', 'InfoLabel2'].agg(lambda x: ', '.join(x))
```

then I receive the dataframe aggregated as expected.

When I do this:

```
  df_temp = df.groupby('Col1', 'Col2')['InfoType', 'InfoLabel1', 'InfoLabel2'].agg(lambda x: ', '.join(x))
```

then I receive the dataframe aggregated as expected.

When I do this:

```
  df_temp = df.groupby('Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3')['InfoType', 'InfoLabel1', 'InfoLabel2'].agg(lambda x: ', '.join(x))
```

then I receive the dataframe aggregated as expected.

But when I do this:

```
  df_temp = df.groupby('Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4')['InfoType', 'InfoLabel1', 'InfoLabel2'].agg(lambda x: ', '.join(x))
```

then I receive an empty dataframe and no error.

However, I do not think that the problem is `Col4` because when I remove `Col2` and I still keep `Col4` then I receive the dataframe aggregated as expected.

Why this is happening?

'Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4' are of different types but I do not think that this is the problem because for example also Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3' are of different types but the aggregation works when I group by only on these.

Can it be related to NAs in these columns?

P.S.

I know that it would better to have specific examples of my data but it would be too time-consuming to post them here and also I do not want to expose my data at all.

**P.S.2**

**I did the following. Before the `groupby`, I filled in the `np.nan` with values (eg -1 for floats and 'NA' for objects) and the code worked so I was probably right at my initial hypothesis about the NAs. Feel free to share ideas why this is happening.**

Comment: can you add your input and expected dataframe please? please see [mcve]

Comment: `columns_not_group` can't have any NA values - this must be a list of the column **names**, not the columns itself. You should check how you created `columns_not_group`.

Comment: @Datanovice, it is a bit time-consuming to do so (without also exposing too much my data). I think that if somebody is experienced in Pandas then he/she may suggest some good hypotheses on why this is happening above (and with no error returned). I suspect that it has to something with NA values in the column values corresponding to columns_not_group but I may be wrong

Comment: @Stef, I meant column values corresponding to columns_not_group - obviously the columns_not_group cannot have any NAs.

Comment: @Datanovice, I did the following. Before the `groupby`, I filled in the `np.nan` with values (eg -1 for floats and 'NA' for objects) and the code worked so I was probably right at my initial hypothesis about the NAs. Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @Stef, I did the following. Before the `groupby`, I filled in the `np.nan` with values (eg -1 for floats and 'NA' for objects) and the code worked so I was probably right at my initial hypothesis about the NAs. Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: It's still quite difficult to say without a reproduction of your data (even if its a few rows) if you posted this to github as an issue I'm pretty sure you'd receive the same response, I think the lack of response is also quite evident of the above. Maybe add a bounty someone more experienced may be able to help but in the first instance just add a few rows of data that can reproduce your issue.

Comment: @Datanovice, if it is few rows (which still exposes my data though) then you may not encounter the problem at all. I think that someone who is experienced in `pandas` would have encountered something similar and can instantly tell.

Comment: you can create dummy data or randomize it

Comment: @Datanovice, if it is dummy then you can simply create them by yourself in the end. And in any case, I think that someone who is experienced in pandas would have encountered something similar and can instantly tell.

Comment: @jezrael, do you have any ideas with your very experienced `pandas` mind about why what is described at my post occurs? :)

Comment: @Datanovice, answer given and with no data example ;)

Comment: my only response is to accept the common community wisdom here [how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215824/discussion-between-outcast-and-datanovice).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason is that in all groups created by all 4 columns is at least one `NA` value. Therefore these groups are excluded and the result is empty. If you take less than 4 columns this condition is obviously not met for your actual data.

See the [docs on missing values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#na-values-in-groupby):

> NA groups in GroupBy are automatically excluded.

Example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[None,1,2], 'b':[1,None,2], 'c': [1,2,None], 'd': [1,1,1]})
>>> df
     a    b    c  d
0  NaN  1.0  1.0  1
1  1.0  NaN  2.0  1
2  2.0  2.0  NaN  1
>>> df.groupby(['a', 'b']).d.sum()
a    b  
2.0  2.0    1
Name: d, dtype: int64
>>> df.groupby(['a', 'c']).d.sum()
a    c  
1.0  2.0    1
Name: d, dtype: int64
>>> df.groupby(['b', 'c']).d.sum()
b    c  
1.0  1.0    1
Name: d, dtype: int64
>>> df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c']).d.sum()
Series([], Name: d, dtype: int64)
```

---

Version 1.1.0 will have a `dropna` parameter in `groupby` to handle this kind of cases. You can set it to `False` to include `NA` values in groupby keys (default is `True` for backward compability), see https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/30584.

Comment: Ok so if this is true then it is what I was saying basically ;)
Or ok let's say generally suspecting - I did not explicitly given a specific explanation.

Comment: so you'll have to wait for 1.1.0 and for the time being fill your NAs, see me updated answer.

Comment: Ok I see thank you. :)  Am I wrong to feel that it is quite "weird" that pandas by default ignores every `groupby` row that simply has an NA in one of its columns (and also `pandas` does not have the option to change that)? I do not see what is the problem with preserving these rows as they are - either conceptually or technically.

Comment: I think this is discussed at length here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/3729 (this issue was opened in 2013!)

Comment: Ok, I see, thanks (upvote) ;) - and indeeds pandas is a bit too silent with regards to something like that which is quite major (although as you mention this is somewhere written in the documentation).